# Structure where the data type of a member differs

Tags: vb.net, structure

Maybe superfluous, but some intro...

I am rewriting an add-in for my CAD-application (using VB.NET).
This add-in reads, via an API, a bunch of metadata from a file, presents it in a Form. This data can then be (partially) changed and written back to the file.

This metadata is accessible in a consistent way, however the data type is not the same everywhere (String, Currency, Date, Boolean, Long and IPictureDisp).

Currently I have a much too complex class with several arrays. I thought it might be smarter to create a structure. The problem is the varying data type.

Is it possible to define a structure with a member with varying datat type, or am I forced to define a different structure for each data type?

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options...

## 1: Use `Object`

Nice and simple, every data type inherits from `Object` - so if your struct contains a property of type `Object`, you can put pretty much any data type in there

[From the docs:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/object-data-type)

> The Object data type can point to data of any data type, including any object instance your application recognizes. Use Object when you do not know at compile time what data type the variable might point to.

However, this does mean that you will get next to no help from the compiler when you are trying to write code using this property. You will also probably have to `cast` any time you need to do anything type-specific

## 2: Generic Types

This will not fit situations where you are not sure of the type. You can create a generic struct using the `Of` syntax.

You'd create it as so:

```
Structure MyStructure(Of T)
    'our changing type
    Dim MyCustomData As T

    '...alongside regular types
    Dim Name As String
    Dim OtherThing As Integer
End Structure
```

and then when you need to create the structure, you'd simply pass the type in and assign the value

```
Dim struct As New MyStructure(Of Integer)
struct.MyCustomData = 123

Dim struct2 As New MyStructure(Of String)
struct2.MyCustomData = "a"
```

Comment: Option 2 looks like the cleanest way.Thanks for the quick response!